# Proving that three numbers are in A.P.

Tags: sequences-and-series

A number $a$ is the Arithmetic Mean(A.M.) between $b$ and $c$, $b$ is the Geometric Mean(G.M.) between $a$ and $c$. Prove that $$\frac{1}{a}, \frac{1}{c} and \frac{1}{b}$$ are in Arithmetic Progressions(A.P.).

I haven't been able to do much, but this is it :

As, $a$ is the A.M. between $b$ and $c$,
$$a = \frac{b+c}{2}$$ or, $$2a = b+c$$

And, $b$ is the G.M. between $a$ and $c$, so, $$b^2 = ac$$ or, $$b = \sqrt{ac}$$How do i proceed next?

Comment: Having you tried proving instead from $\frac{1}{c} - \frac{1}{a} = \frac{1}{b} - \frac{1}{c}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $a$ is the Arithmetic mean, it lies between $b$ and $c$. But, as $b$ is the geometric mean it will lie between $a$ and $c$. This can only mean that $a=b$. And *because* $a=\frac{b+c}{2}$,  $a=b=c$. Clearly,$\frac{1}{a}= \frac{1}{c} = \frac{1}{b}$ and therefore, trivially, in AP.

Comment: I think that the non-trivial case is a spurious solution resulting from squaring

Comment: @Henry oh right. I didn't notice. I am doing a rollback.

Comment: $a=\frac c 4$ yields $b<0$

Comment: @alex yeah, it was a spurious solution. I undid my edit.

Comment: @Sabyasachi Sorry, I was too quick...

Comment: @alex not a big deal, it can be hard to keep track of edits.

Answer (score 1):

Write $b = 2a - c$ so that $b^2 = (2a - c)^2$.  Then with the additional condition $b^2 = ac$, eliminate $b$ and obtain an equation in $a, c$.  Factor this equation and consider two cases, one of which is $a = c$.

Comment: wait, there is another case except $a=b=c$? I overlooked something then maybe.

Comment: I only hinted at considering the nontrivial case; I intended the OP to figure out the issues that arise from considering this case.

Comment: I deleted my comment solving the equation.

Comment: No, it's fine.  You haven't given away everything.  One just has to be careful about the notion of geometric mean.

Comment: This only works if you think that $-2$ is the geometric mean of $1$ and $4$, or that $2$ is the geometric mean of $-1$ and $-4$.  I would not accept this, and the reciprocals are then not in arithmetic progression